# How to form a Binary Tree from a Preorder and a Children charsequence

Tags: algorithm, recursion, binary-tree, preorder

The problem is to build a Binary Tree from a Preorder listing and a sequence of the number of children that each node has. For example: "BAC" and "200" could be one input resulting in an inorder listing of "ABC".

My current method is to check the second charsequence (the one with the numbers) for '2', it has two children, '0',it has no children, 'L', it has a left child, and 'R', it has a right child. To do this I use this method:

```
public static BinaryTree preOrderBuild(CharSequence charElements,
        CharSequence childCodes) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub.
    BinaryTree build = new BinaryTree();
    char first;
    if (childCodes.length() == 0) {
        return new BinaryTree();
    } else {
        first = childCodes.charAt(0);
    }
    if (first == '2') {
        int sum = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < childCodes.length(); i++) {
            if (childCodes.charAt(i) == 'R' || childCodes.charAt(i) == 'L')
                sum += 0;
            else if (childCodes.charAt(i) == '2')
                sum += 1;
            else if (childCodes.charAt(i) == '0')
                sum--;
            if (sum == 0) {
                BinaryTree Left = preOrderBuild(
                        charElements.subSequence(1, i + 1),
                        childCodes.subSequence(1, i + 1));
                BinaryTree Right = preOrderBuild(
                        charElements.subSequence(i + 1,
                                charElements.length()),
                        childCodes.subSequence(i + 1, childCodes.length()));
                build.merge(charElements.charAt(0), Left, Right);
            }
        }
    } else if (first == 'R' || first == 'r') {
        BinaryTree right = preOrderBuild(
                charElements.subSequence(1, charElements.length()),
                childCodes.subSequence(1, childCodes.length()));
        build.merge(charElements.charAt(0), new BinaryTree(), right);
    } else if (first == 'L' || first == 'l') {
        BinaryTree left = preOrderBuild(
                charElements.subSequence(1, charElements.length()),
                childCodes.subSequence(1, childCodes.length()));
        build.merge(charElements.charAt(0), left, new BinaryTree());
    } else {
        build.merge(charElements.charAt(0), new BinaryTree(),
                new BinaryTree());
    }
    return build;
}
```

which basically processes the childCodes sequence to determine where each branch of the tree breaks off. The problem is that for larger trees it only processes the first few items and then collapses. (an example of the larger tree is : "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU" with child code "220022002200LRR20RLL0")

Answer (score 2):

If you go from right to left, you don't need to do any recursion.

```java
Stack<BinaryTree> stack = new Stack<BinaryTree>();

for (int i = childCodes.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    char code = childCodes.charAt(i);
    char name = charElements.charAt(i);
    if (code == '0') {
        stack.push(new BinaryTree(name, null, null));
    }
    else if (code == 'L') {
        stack.push(new BinaryTree(name, stack.pop(), null));
    }
    else if (code == 'R') {
        stack.push(new BinaryTree(name, null, stack.pop()));
    }
    else if (code == '2') {
        stack.push(new BinaryTree(name, stack.pop(), stack.pop()));
    }
}

return stack.pop();
```

With your data, it produces the following tree:

```
A
+-B
| +-C
| '-D
'-E
  +-F
  | +-G
  | '-H
  '-I
    +-J
    | +-K
    | '-L
    '-M
      +-N
      | +-(null)
      | '-O
      |   +-(null)
      |   '-P
      |     +-Q
      |     '-R
      |       +-(null)
      |       '-S
      |         +-T
      |         | +-U
      |         | '-(null)
      |         '-(null)
      '-(null)
```